# QTableView: resize all columns on double click on column header

Tags: qt4

When doublecliking on the edge of a single column header, that column is resized to fit to contents.
If one selects multiple columns, how is it possible to resize all the selected columns when one double clicks on the edge of any of the selected columns headers?

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect some slot to `QHeaderView::sectionHandleDoubleClicked` signal
2. In that slot get the selected columns.
3. Autoresize them using `QHeaderView::setResizeMode` and `QHeaderView::ResizeToContents`.
4. Get new absolute column sizes.
5. Revert column resize modes to `QHeaderView::Interactive` or whatever they were.
6. Set new absolute column sizes using `QHeaderView::resizeSection`.

An example:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        QList<QStandardItem*> items;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
            QChar ch = QString::number(j).at(0);
            item->setText(QString().fill(ch, 20));

            items << item;
        }

        model->appendRow(items);
    }

    view = new QTableView;
    view->setModel(model);

    connect(view->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionHandleDoubleClicked(int)),
            this, SLOT(sectionHandleDoubleClicked(int)));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(view);
}

void Widget::sectionHandleDoubleClicked(int logicalIndex)
{
    QHeaderView *header = view->horizontalHeader();

    QModelIndexList list = view->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();

    QSet<int> columns;
    Q_FOREACH (QModelIndex index, list)
    {
        if (index.isValid())
        {
            columns.insert(index.column());
        }
    }

    Q_FOREACH (int column, columns)
    {
        header->setResizeMode(column, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
        int newWidth = header->sectionSize(column);
        header->setResizeMode(column, QHeaderView::Interactive);
        header->resizeSection(column, newWidth);
    }
}
```